# SetTimeout with Promise.resolve not outputting string but a numerical value of string, why?

Tags: javascript, promise, settimeout

I'm trying to use a setTimeout method with a Promise.resolve format. I think I am close to getting it, but I am not getting what I expected in my console.

```js
const good = Promise.resolve(setTimeout(() => 'success', 4000));
console.log(good);

//prints '51' instead of 'success'
```

I think that '51' is the numerical value of success. If I am correct I am wondering why it is printing that instead of the string isteald if it is in quotation marks.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Edit: To clarify, this was a challenge given to me by a Udemy instructor. I was asking why my specific code wasn't working not for answers.

This is the challenge:

```
const success = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         if (true) {
             setTimeout(resolve, 4000, 'success')
         } else {
             reject('error it broke')
         }
     });

    success 
        .then (() => console.log('success!'))


3. Read about Promise.resolve() and Promise.reject(). How can you make 
the above promise shorter with Promise.resolve() and console log "success"
```

When I was looking this up, it didn't appear that this was feasible but it was challenge so I figured I was missing something.

I hope this helps clarify things

Comment: I would expect it to print `Promise<51>`, actually. And the return value of `setTimeout()` is a handle that you can pass to `clearTimeout()`.

Comment: When you console.log, what is the output? I expect it returns a resolved promise?

Comment: I included the output that I got as a comment with the code snipped @EddieDelRio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout()` doesn't "just work" with promises. You have to resolve a promise with the string value like this, and log your output within a `.then()`:

```js
const good = new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 4000, 'success');
});

good.then(result => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: I edited my post to explain why I was trying to write my function with Promises.resolve

Comment: You can't use `Promise.resolve()` with an asynchronous callback-style function. `Promise.resolve()` is for casting _synchronous_ values to an immediately resolved promise. Either way though, this is definitely shorter than the edit you've provided.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now. I can't pass a value with in the format that I have written but I can do that with Promise.resolve() to a Promise that has already been executed. Therefore, if I am following correctly, setTimeout would attached to the Promise executed first, then the value "success" would be passed with Promise.resolve()? I am following what you've said correctly?

Comment: _but I can do that with Promise.resolve() to a Promise that has already been executed_ no, that's not what [`Promise.resolve()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) is for. You should read the documentation there. If you wanted the value `'success'` converted to a `Promise`, you can do `Promise.resolve('success').then(result => ...)`, but if you want the value `'success'` 4 seconds later, you _cannot_ use `Promise.resolve()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying for me @PatrickRoberts, I really appreciate this learning experience because of the depth of your explanation. It helped me out a lot and what you are saying makes more sense to me because from the examples I saw, I didn't see a place for setTimeout with Promise.resolve but the question confused me. I will most definitely look into the documentation and I appreciate your patience with me

Comment: @A-Bro I'd take online tutorials with a grain of salt. You'll get much more reliable information on JavaScript from documentation like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org) and from asking questions on Stack Overflow. Regarding promises, I'd say [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) is one of the best users on here. Check out some of his answers if you want a deeper understanding of how promises work.

Comment: Thank you very much for passing along this extra info and helping me further develop my skills/understanding. I actually prefer to look at MDN for help with things and your link actually led to what page I was looking at when I trying to get things to work. It gave me the idea that what I was trying to do wasn't exactly feasible or the best

Answer (score 0):

Promises don't return an explicit value. It returns a either resolved or rejected promise object. Look into async operations with js more. But in the meantime, try

`good.then(expectedGoodValue => console.log(expectedGoodValue));`

If you want to define good, you'll have to do it in the `then` block of a promise. Be warned though, if you try to use good outside of the promise, it may come back undefined.

```js
var good;

new  Promise.resolve(setTimeout(() => 'success', 4000))
.then(value => 
{
  good = value;
})
.then(() =>
{
  //some other operation
  console.log(good); //Won't be undefined
});


console.log(good); //More than likely will be undefined. This line may be hit before the async resolves
```